# Generating a random, dense set of points subject to proximity restrictions?

Tags: computational-geometry

I recently read a paper about hyperuniform distributions, which mentioned that one way to generate a rectangle filled with hyperuniformly-distributed points is the following:

1. Choose a uniformly-random location in the rectangle.
2. If that location is not within distance $r$ of any previously-chosen point, add a new point at that location.
3. Repeat until all locations are within distance $r$ of a previously-chosen point.

It's not too hard to do this by sitting in a loop choosing random locations and comparing that location against every previously-chosen point, adding the location in if it isn't too close to anything else. We can speed up the test in part (2) by using something like an R-tree or a dynamically-rebuilt k-d tree.

However, I'm not sure how to answer the following questions:

1. How do we efficiently tell when every location in the rectangle is within $r$ units from some previously-chosen point? In other words, is there an efficient data structure for maintaining a rectangle and a set of circles in that rectangle in a way that efficiently answers queries of the form "is there an uncovered location in the rectangle?"
2. Is there an efficient way to uniformly sample from the free space in the rectangle other than doing rejection sampling? From the behavior I've seen with the programs I've written so far it's not at all uncommon for there to be just a tiny sliver of free space left in the rectangle that's extremely unlikely to be hit by choosing points in the rectangle uniformly at random and just hoping that we end up in it.

Thanks!

Comment: One approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching.  Alternatively, if you found a good data structure to store a union of discs and that could handle stabbing queries efficiently, that'd work too.

Comment: @D.W. I'm aware of those general techniques, but it doesn't seem like they're good for the opposite problem of "find free space" or "sample uniformly from a distribution." Thanks, though!

Comment: They answer your question 1.  I agree that we can hope for better answers to question 2.  Have you tried using a quad-tree, where your sampling involves a random walk down the tree, but pruned to avoid visiting regions that are already completely covered?